# Hibernate Restrictions ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a `Teacher` class that contains a list of courses and now I do not know how to make a filtration on this list of courses using hibernate `criteria` and restrictions?

```
public class Teacher extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
   @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Course.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private Set<Course> courses;
}

public class TeacherSearchCriteria extends Criteria { 
    private Course course; 
}
```

Here is my service class that provides restriction logic:

```
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    List<Teacher> result = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

    CriteriaQuery<Teacher> criteria = builder.createQuery(Teacher.class);
    Root<Teacher> from = criteria.from(Teacher.class);

    if (searchCriteria != null) {
        List<Predicate> restrictions = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

        if (searchCriteria.getCourse() != null) {
            //Here I don't know how to make the restrictions on Set of 
            //courses
            restrictions.add(builder.equal(from.get("courses"), 
            searchCriteria.getCourse()));
        }
        addRestrictionsToCriteria(restrictions, criteria, builder);
    }
```

Comment: create an alias for courses and then reference the alias in the Restriction.  I will try to post a full answer in a little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [alias](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations) for your collection.  You can then add restrictions against properties in the collection.  The creation of the alias tells hibernate to perform the join to the table when it constructs the sql.

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
List<Teacher> result = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

CriteriaQuery<Teacher> criteria = builder.createQuery(Teacher.class);
criteria.createAlias("courses", "c")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("c", searchCriteria.getCourse());
```